# How to fill column in .csv with variations?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a pretty simple sort of question here. All I need to do is, well you know how you can fill the whole column down with what's written in the first row of the column?

What I need to do is have a few different variations of text and fill all of them down each row.

Here's an example: say the variations of text are: `text 1`, `text 2` and `text 3`.

I'd need it to fill down the column like this:

```
text 1
text 2
text 3
text 1
text 2
text 3
etc.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How do you select one set? what do you mean grab fill handle? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If A1 is test 1, A2 is test 2 and A3 is test 3, put `=A1` in A4 and drag it down.

Comment: Drag what down exactly? You mean drag down the row I put "=A1" in?

Comment: Drag the fill handle. The little square thing that appears on the right bottom of a highlighted cell.